# How to render a text with linebreak saved from a textarea form?

Tags: 8, theming

Unfortunately I haven't found anything on the web with this specific problem.

I have a field (text, formatted, long) and a form with a textarea element that should save the entered text to this field.

Now I want to render it in my twig template. I access the value like this in my controller:

```
'text' => $node->field_text->value
```

And I render it in twig normally:

```
<p>{{ text }}</p>
```

But whenever I entered a new line by pressing enter in the textarea, it doesn't render the new line. The same thing in the CKEditor when I edit the node and look at the content, there's no new line.
[image: textarea][image: ckeditor][image: dpm]

I'm sure that there's a linebreak though, because when I `dpm()` this value, it prints that.

I tried putting the value in a `'#markup' => $text` render array, but it was the same. How can I render this new line?

Comment: What is in dpm? In your CKEditor it does not seem you have a new line there.

Comment: as @Refilion says , you have a problem in your CKEditor since the <br /> not added when you hit enter, focus on that problem and the rendering problem will be resolved auto.

Comment: @Refilon dpm() is a function of the devel module to print an input into the Drupal message area. And yes, as I stated, the CKEditor didn't show the new line even though I entered it in a custom form - and I wanted to keep using the custom form, not the editor. But thanks for the comments, the problem is solved (see accepted answer) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried putting the value in a `'#markup' => $text` render array, but it
>   was the same. How can I render this new line?

Yes, you need to put the text in a render element, but for a formatted text field the correct element is `processed_text`:

```
'text' => [
  '#type' => 'processed_text',
  '#text' => $node->field_text->value,
  '#format' => $node->field_text->format,
],
```